# Create an ongoing background Service

Tags: android, android-service

I want to create a light weight background service that remains active.

I do not want to perform any continuous operations in this service. Only once-in-a-while, like every 30 mins it wakes up & checks something.

I know I can not assure that a background service will remain alive throughout.

But what is the best approach to create such a lightweight service.

I've noticed that services like Facebook messenger are always running in background under normal conditions. So how can I achieve this?

Thank You

Comment: "Only once-in-a-while, like every 30 mins it wakes up & checks something" -- then why does it need to be continuously running? Why not use `AlarmManager`? [Only have services running when they are *actively* delivering value to the user](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/27/role-services.html). Sitting around doing nothing is not actively delivering value to the user.